# What does “totes” mean in this case?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Or because he found her occupation **totes** hilarious?
> <sub>Source: [The Age, *Wink is no laughing matter for Prime Minister with a 'women problem'*](http://www.theage.com.au/federal-politics/political-opinion/wink-is-no-laughing-matter-for-prime-minister-with-a-women-problem-20140521-38okz.html)</sub>

It seems like the word “totes” is an intransitive verb, and “hilarious” is the predicative for her occupation. But the case isn’t shown in dictionaries. Is this really the case, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: You might find [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/15194/32) helpful.

Comment: @StoneyB, Lack of imagination blocks my way even to look up the very word that I’m looking in the dictionaries, not uncommonly. Thank you very much. There would be totes no way to forget the word after having read your linked explanation.

Comment: I wouldn't get too hung up over this one. Although @Lucian has managed to find a [dictionary definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/totes), it's a very recent and very limited currency slang usage that might well vanish as quickly as it appeared.

Comment: Totes, @FumbleFingers, totes ma goats.

Comment: @Jay: Back in the 50s it was ***hip*** to say things like *"You're such a **square, man**"*. But by the 70s it was decidedly ***uncool*** to use the word "square" at all. Some words come and go, some come and stay. But sometimes it's hard to abandon the slang you picked up in your teens - which originally gave you the kudos of being ***turned on and tuned in***, but decades later simply identifies you as being an ***ole fart***. In short, *be careful what you learn*, and be prepared to discard some of it later.

Comment: @FumbleFingers lol, oh trust me, I know.  That was the emphasis totes I was using there.  Because, you know, slang can be confusing ;).  But yeah, idiomatic phrases are of little use if you don't speak the language all the freaking time.  Basically because of what you said above.  Slang can be quite faddish.  Eh sport?

Comment: @Jay: ***Sport?*** Haven't heard *that* one in a coon's age! Actually, all it makes me think of is totally unconvincing late-middle-aged fathers in Hollywood movies talking to their 8-year-old son - who if they have a *daughter*, invariably refer to her as either ***Princess*** or (yuck! :) ***pumpkin***.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lucian Sava got the fundamentals right, "totes" is basically a shortening of "totally".  But there is another thing to keep in mind, "totes" is a slang word, so it has a lot of implied meaning on top of it's literal definition.

It depends on the age really (from what I've seen).  A lot of teenagers and people in their early 20's simply use "totes" to add emphasis to the word that follows it.  So, "that book is totes awesome" would translate as "that book is extremely awesome".

It gets a bit more complex when you get to the (slightly) older generation, about 23 ~ 35.  I think we've all taken to making fun of people who use "totes" as mentioned above.  So when we say "totes" we usually mean it in a sarcastic fashion.  So, if I were to say, "that book is totes awesome" I would probably mean, "that book would only be good if I were a shallow teenager."  Though I don't always use it in such a mean way, I have before, and I have a lot of friends who do.

In other cases, I have seen people use it simply to add some silliness/humor to what they are saying.  "I totes love broccoli, it's my hero!" said in the right context may simply mean the speaker is trying to add a certain degree of humor or silliness to their statement.

Point being, the word is "idiomatic slang", so you need to be careful when you see it used.  It could simply be being used for emphasis or, possibly, it is being used sarcastically.  Like all social idioms, pay close attention to the context in which the word is used and you should be fine.

Comment: Well put.  I would add that the technical term for the sarcastic and silly/humorous usage is **ironic**.  The older generation uses the term **ironically**.

Comment: @Codeswitcher - I dunno, using the word "ironic" on the internet usually just leads to an argument...

Comment: I think we're now required to quarrel both to prove your point, and to provide the straight line for somebody to quip, "Well, isn't that ironic."

Comment: @JayCarr, I really appreciate your answer, is good indeed, +1 from me too. The OP did the right thing selecting your answer. However you still owe me a lamb, for you mistakenly took me as a lady.

Comment: @LucianSava Ack!  Sorry!  My left pinkie gets a little crazy sometimes and adds 'a's to things...  No offense intended, I'll get the lamb in the mail later today ;)

Comment: @Codeswitcher What?  There's no need to argue!  Why, I would rather say that arguing over 'irony' is the antithesis of how the internet functions!  I do say, good sir, why doust thou oppress me so?  (ps, that's totes ironic sarcasm...I think.)

Answer (score 3):

Totes [see dictionary](https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=cr&ei=3IN8U7LMHOGfyQOd8IDoAQ#q=define+totes) is an adverb and means totally