# Usage of "so" as an intensifier for adjectives

Tags: grammar, adjectives, intensifiers

In the following sentences "so" acts as an intensifier for the subsequent adjectives.

> 1. This car is so expensive. (okay)
> 2. This so expensive car is John's car. (bad)

Can we determine that "so" cannot be used to modify an adjective modifying the subject of a sentence?

> 1. This car is so expensive. (okay)
> 2. I ate a so expensive pizza. (bad)

Can we determine that "so" cannot be used in conjunction with a transitive verb/object noun?

As far as I understand, "so" used as an adjective intensifier must be used with a copula verb and cannot be used to intensify a subject-modifying adjective. Are these the exhaustive rules or are there other outlying examples?

Comment: I would argue that your version (1) is only OK if it is part of a longer sentence that mentions a consequence of the car being so expensive, such as "This car is so expensive, that I don't see how anybody can afford it."

Comment: Another question asked about "[You are so offended.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74170)"

Comment: @Jasper Or if it was an exclamation. "This car is so expensive!"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz -- As I argued in the linked post, the same grammar rule applies to both sentences and exclamations.

Comment: The apple pie tasted so good. This computer is out-of-date. (Webster). We can use so + adjective  on its own in informal English.

Answer (score 1):

Use **so** with adjectives or adverbs alone.
They always finish **so** quickly.
The movie was **so** bad that I left halfway through.

When you're modifying nouns or noun phrases, use **such (a)**.
Subject:
**Such** bad jokes will probably offend somebody.
Object:
I've always considered him **such a** thoughtless guy.

Therefore, since a subject has to be a noun/noun phrase/noun clause, etc., it is very unlikely that you'll see **so** modifying the subject.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is so expensive.
2. This car is so expensive.

3  This so expensive car is John's car.

4. I ate a so expensive pizza.

The sentences #1 and #2 are grammatical.

As for the #3 and #4, they are not grammatical.  You don't use so + adjective + noun.  You can rephrase these sentences as follows:

This is John's car that's so expensive.

I ate such an expensive pizza or I ate a pizza that's so expensive.